# Tabs on Silver.UI not updating

Tags: c#, toolbox

I need to programitically add tabs to a Silver.UI toolbox after load, and after I add the tabs and call refresh, it still does not show them. But for some reason, when I put the code in load, it works! Here's my code:

```
//Load the objects into the desinger
DesignDeserializer deserializer = new DesignDeserializer();
deserializer.load();

public void createTab(string title)
    {
        ToolBoxTab tab = new ToolBoxTab(title, 1);
        objectBox.AddTab(tab);
        objectBox.RefreshTabs();
    }
```

Here's my DesignDeserializer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Silver.UI;

namespace EmuGUI
{
    class DesignDeserializer : main
    {
        public void load()
        {
            //Send to create the tabs...
            createTab("foo");
        }
    }
}
```

It does not give me any errors...